# Why do I need to spread operator in the getter method?

Tags: dart

so right now,  I'm learning about provider state management from maximillian on udemy, and he keeps using spread operator as a getter. For example:

```
 List<Order> _orders = [];

  List<Order> get orders {
    return [..._orders];
  }
```

Why do we need to use the spread operator?

I can use this code and it runs fine.

```
List<Order> _orders = [];

  List<Order> get orders {
    return _orders;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two examples is that in the first example you are creating a new list containing the elements from `_orders`. This will make it so if somebody are trying to add a new element to the list returned from `orders`, it will not make any changes to `_orders`.

In the second example, you are returning a reference to the `_orders` list. So any modifications to the list returned from `orders` will happen to the `_orders` list.

Comment: Keep in mind it's a shallow copy, so someone could still alter the objects *within* the objects of your list.  You'd need a deep copy to prevent that.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the spread operator you are making a new list, and not returning the current one you have.
The only reason I can't think of is to be defensive about the data in the list and that it could be modified from outside the object.

> TLDR:

Here you get a reference to the list and you could potentially modify it.

```
  List<Order> get orders {
    return _orders;
  }
```

And here you are defensive about your data and return a new copy each time the getter gets called.
So the user cannot modify the list wihtout using other method of your class.

```
  List<Order> get orders {
    return [..._orders];
  }
```